# Does Ardunino serial need a common ground

Tags: arduino

I have a device running off a different power supply, that I'm trying to talk to serially, it has TX and RX lines, GND and 2.7+ line, its quite grunty so It has its own PS.

I'm getting some odd results at the moment, so wondering if I need to use a common GND between the Arduino GND and the PS GND and the device GND.

Does serial require a common voltage reference point?

Its a mega 2560 R3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*All* signals require a reference voltage. Ground is what provides this reference for single-ended signals such as those used by a UART.

Comment: ah so that would cause spurious characters if no GND?

Answer (score 3):

UART signals are composed of low-level and high-level signals.

The receptor, at the other end, to be able to understand your UART signal, must be aware of what is that low-level and high-level signals.

So you must put your UART GND to the GND of the receptor, and the high-level voltage must correspond to the TTL input level of your receptor.

For example, if the high-level of your UART is 2.7v, and your receptor input-level is 5v, you could encounter bad level detections sometime, because 2.7v could be detected as a low-level input.

For the low-level inputs, this is no problem because 0v is always 0v.

Comment: Yes, luckily Arduino TTL is quite variable, perhaps 2.8 to 5 volts... it takes a hammering and still works

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but... didn't you break your 2.7V device? Besides using a common ground, like Ignacio pointed out, when you have to interface something to something else you should ALWAYS check what are the correct voltage levels expected.

So did you check that the high voltage levels and low voltage levels are fulfilled? I think not. Because:

1. Arduino Uno (i just have the 328P datasheet on hand, so i'll use this) has an Atmega328P powered at 5V. The datasheet says that the Vih parameter (the minimum voltage sensed as a "high" value) is 0.6Vcc, which means 3V. So if you send him a 2.7V signal.... You are doing something wrong.
2. The 2.7V device has probably an absolute maximum voltage allowed on any pin of Vcc+0.3V. This means that the maximum voltage for each pin is 3V; if you go above this current starts flowing through the protection diode and... you blow your device. Now you are giving it 5V, so.... Puff...

If the above criteria are not fulfilled you have to put between the two circuits something. Which is

- a resistor divider if you have to make the voltage lower (just two resistors) and a couple of transistors to make it higher
- Opto-isolators (and you can keep the grounds separated)
- Voltage translators (such as TXS0102)
- other...

Comment: yep i was following a tutorial for inner test pads of a device, externally its 3volt batteries, but the test pad is without batteries and after the regulator, and specifies 2.7v

Comment: So... make sure that you are inside the chip's specs... Otherwise you may damage it...

Comment: Luckily it did not damage it, and I have a happy connection.